# Correct flow type of an HOC that converts props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have a component `Form` that takes these props: `{ data: ?RecordType, onSave: RecordType => void}`.
I want to wrap it up in an HOC that will take in an additional prop `{id: string}` and inject a prop `data` in the wrapped component.
How will I type such component?

```
export function withOneDetails<
  RecordType: {},
  DefaultProps: {},
  ReceivedProps: { id: string },
  AddedProps: { data: ?RecordType },
  InnerProps: DefaultProps & AddedProps,
  OuterProps: DefaultProps & ReceivedProps
>(
  Comp: React.ComponentType<InnerProps>
): React.ComponentType<OuterProps> {
  return props => {
    ... call api
    return (
      <Comp {...props} data={data} />
    );
  }
}

const EditForm = withOneDetails(Form);

const b = () => <Form />
const a = () => <EditForm />
```

On the last line (`const a`), I want to receive a flow error that I didn't provide `id` and `onSave`. But I got no errors.

`const b` correctly shows errors about `data` and `onSave` being missing.